# Random SQL query that ALLOW REPEATS of certain IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that allows repeats for *specific* items (if the items has an mID from 270-279). I have a query that searches through several categories for a number of random items in each category.

```
$query = 
(SELECT mID, mName, mType, mRar 
FROM mcitems 
WHERE (mRar = '1') AND (mType='13') 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10) 

UNION 

(SELECT mID, mName, mType, mRar 
FROM mcitems 
WHERE (mRar = '3') AND (mType='13') 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3);
```

So, if the mID is 270-279, it should allow a repeat ... but not allow repeats for other mIDs.

Right now, if I have a LIMIT of 10 ... but there are only 2 items in that category with an mID between 270-279, it will only show 2 items. Can someone tell me how to do this?

For example ...
**EXAMPLE OF ORIGINAL TABLE** ....

```
| mID  | mName   | mType | mRar |
|:---- |:-------:| :----:|-----:|
| 268  | Object1 |   13  |   1  |
| 269  | Object2 |   13  |   1  |
| 270  | Object3 |   13  |   1  |
| 271  | Object4 |   13  |   1  |
| 276  | Object5 |   13  |   1  |
| 278  | Object6 |   13  |   3  |
| 283  | Object7 |   13  |   3  |
```

... then the query should spew 10 randoms items with mRar=1, and 3 random items with mRar=3 ... but there are only 5 items (268, 269, 279, 271, 276) with mRar=1 and 2 items (278, 283) with mRar=3 ... and final result is 7 unique items.

Ideally, for items with mID>=270 && mID<280, I want those items to be able to repeat ...

**EXAMPLE OF QUERY "DESIRED" OUTPUT**
(This is AN example, since RANDOM items would give different results)

```
| mID  | mName   | mType | mRar |    What is happening                 |
|:---- |:-------:|:-----:|:----:|--------------------------------------:
| 268  | Object1 |   13  |   1  |The 1st item where mRar=1             |
| 269  | Object2 |   13  |   1  |268<270, so this row only used once   | 
| 270  | Object3 |   13  |   1  |IDs of 270-279 can be repeated...     | 
| 271  | Object4 |   13  |   1  |... so, to reach 10 items, the items  |
| 276  | Object5 |   13  |   1  |between 270-279 are RANDOMLY repeated |
| 270  | Object3 |   13  |   1  |                                      | 
| 271  | Object4 |   13  |   1  |                                      | 
| 276  | Object5 |   13  |   1  |                                      | 
| 270  | Object3 |   13  |   1  |                                      | 
| 276  | Object5 |   13  |   1  | The 10th item where mRar=1           | 
| 278  | Object6 |   13  |   3  | The 1st item where mRar=3            | 
| 283  | Object7 |   13  |   3  |                                      | 
| 278  | Object6 |   13  |   3  | Again, IDs of 270-279 can be repeated|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Added some example tables....

Comment: Can't you just "fill the gap" when you are processing the data later on in PHP? "Making up" more data than actually exists, usually requires jumping through quite some hoops in SQL ...

Comment: I'm trying to get this done as simple as possible ...  I COULD count how many results are posted, and then REQUERY another round ... but that seems very INEFFICIENT

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.